# Check whether dates are within the date range in selenium web driver ( Java)

Tags: java, date, selenium

In my website, I can select a date range and list all the transactions within the date range. My test case is to verify whether listed transactions dates are within the selected date range .

This is my code. I get all the transaction dates into a LinkedList. Comp_Dates method will compare the actual date is within the ‘From’ and ‘To’ dates.
The problem is this code will always return True. I have changed the FromDate and ToDate to test the false scenario, But still code will return True.

Can you please help? What’s the problem in this code?

```
//Set From Date
        driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderMain_container_container_Block_172_tabPanelMyAccounts_dtDateFrom_txtDate")).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "a"),"01/03/2016");
        //Set To date
        driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderMain_container_container_Block_172_tabPanelMyAccounts_dtDateTo_txtDate")).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "a"),"30/04/2016");
          driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderMain_container_container_Block_172_tabPanelMyAccounts_btnList")).click();


 List<WebElement> Date = 
 driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*  [@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderMain_container_container_Block_172_tabPanelMyAccounts_stxOutstandingTransactions_gvOSTransactions']/tbody/tr[*]/td[1]"));

List<String> Dates = new LinkedList<String>();

for(int i=0;i<Date.size();i++)    
        {    
            Dates.add(Date.get(i).getText());    
            System.out.println(Dates);
        }    

        boolean result = comp_Dates(Dates);

        if (result=true)
        {
        System.out.println(result + ", Address are within the range");
        }
        else 
        {
        System.out.println(result + ", Addresses are not within the range. Test Case Failed");
        }
    }

         private static boolean comp_Dates(List<String> Dates)  {
             try
             {
             SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                //Date date = fmt.parse("2013-05-06");
                String FromDate= "01/05/2016";
                String ToDate= "30/06/2016";
                java.util.Date Fdate =fmt.parse(FromDate);
                java.util.Date Tdate =fmt.parse(ToDate);

             for(String e : Dates) 
                { 
                    java.util.Date ActualDate = fmt.parse(e);       
                 if (ActualDate.compareTo(Fdate)>=0 & ActualDate.compareTo(Tdate)<=0 );
                    {
                        return true;

                    }

                 }
             }
             catch (Exception ex ){
                  System.out.println(ex);
               }
            return false;

             }

            }
```

Transactions dates in Linked list is [18/04/2016, 14/04/2016, 13/04/2016]
I have specified dates as below in the code.

String FromDate= "01/05/2016";

String ToDate= "30/06/2016";

When compare these dates, code should return false as dates doesn’t fall on within From and To dates. But it returns True. What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: `if (result=true)` might be the culprit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are returning true, it will exit the function whenever it founds a date in the range. Thus it would not check for all dates in the list.

If you want to check for all dates, proper `comp_Dates` method could be:

```
    //Set From Date
    driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderMain_container_container_Block_172_tabPanelMyAccounts_dtDateFrom_txtDate")).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "a"), "01/03/2016");
    //Set To date
    driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderMain_container_container_Block_172_tabPanelMyAccounts_dtDateTo_txtDate")).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "a"), "30/04/2016");
    driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderMain_container_container_Block_172_tabPanelMyAccounts_btnList")).click();


    List<WebElement> Date =
            driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*  [@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderMain_container_container_Block_172_tabPanelMyAccounts_stxOutstandingTransactions_gvOSTransactions']/tbody/tr[*]/td[1]"));


    for (int i = 0; i < Date.size(); i++) {
        String date = Date.get(i).getText();
        boolean result = comp_Dates(date);

        if (result) {
            System.out.println(result + ", Address are within the range");
        } else {
            System.out.println(result + ", Addresses are not within the range. Test Case Failed");
        }
    }

private static boolean comp_Dates(String date) {
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

        String FromDate = "01/05/2016";
        String ToDate = "30/06/2016";

        java.util.Date Fdate = fmt.parse(FromDate);
        java.util.Date Tdate = fmt.parse(ToDate);
        java.util.Date ActualDate = fmt.parse(date);

        if (ActualDate.compareTo(Fdate) >= 0 && ActualDate.compareTo(Tdate) <= 0) {
            return true;
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
    return false;
}
```

N.B: There are many typos in your code. You should fix these.

Comment: Thanks Shahid for the reply. I have edit the code as above, but it still returns true.

Comment: Still doesn't work. Always return true.                                                   Output:                                                                                                       true, Dates are within the range
true, Dates are within the range
true, Dates are within the range
PASSED: SelectDateRange

===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================

Comment: Then you should recheck the value from `Date.get(i).getText()`, whether it is returning the exact date.

Comment: Date.get(i).get(Text) return dates as expected.                                     true, Dates are within the range
18/04/2016
true, Dates are within the range
14/04/2016
true, Dates are within the range
13/04/2016

Comment: Hi Shahid, There was a syntax error in if statements (if (ActualDate.compareTo(Fdate)>=0 && ActualDate.compareTo(Tdate)<=0 );)  where I have put a semi colon at the end of the statement. That has stopped getting the correct result. (not sure why eclipse didn't show the syntax error) It's working now. Your code is correct. Thank you very much and appreciate your help :)